# Under what context do kills add towards bounty progression in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

I have been playing Taken King on Xbox One, and so far, bounties have been pretty self explanatory.

Today I picked up a bounty for killing a certain amount of enemies, in a certain amount of time, for a total of five times using heavy weapons. I then proceeded to patrol The Moon, and complete patrol missions.

In a battle, I killed an enemy with the heavy, before swapping to my primary. Apart from that one enemy, I did not even inflict damage with the heavy. After the battle, I found I had earned 1/5 towards my heavy bounty.

Later on, I scored a multi-kill with my super ability. This counted towards the bounty, aswell.

I was then notified, while not engaged in combat, that I had earned another 2/5 of my bounty. The bounty soon completed, with me barley bringing out my heavy, to begin with.

I thought that maybe it had counted kills from nearby players? I was not playing in a party, or as part of a fire team. Perhaps it is a bug or a glitch, but this makes me question the actual inclusion towards bounties.

**What counts towards a "*kill X amount of enemies in Y seconds, Z times, with a certain weapon type*" bounty?**

Comment: Sounds bugged to me. Consider yourself lucky. Normally, I find these sorts of bounties to be a royal pain.

Comment: I agree @Iszi. its my most hated bounty. Fairly new to destiny tho so im not sure if bounties are suppose to be shared with players nearby, or of theres a delay, or what.

Comment: Some bounties do get shared with nearby players, especially if you're in a Fireteam with them. To a certain degree this is by design - i.e.: if you worked a bounty target down to within an inch of his life, and someone else took the shot that finished him off, you wouldn't want to not get credit towards the bounty for your hard work. In this particular case though, if you actually haven't been using your heavy weapon for most of the bounty, there could be a bug.

Comment: Now, if you made one hit each on X enemies with your heavy, and someone else finished them all off with a grenade or super, it's possible that could have been tracked as credit towards the bounty. This is completely different from not using your heavy at all, and fits more probably into the ream of "working as designed" even if it might not exactly be what you'd expect.

Comment: I know the time frame is rather short. There used to be a bounty of killing 7 enemies with a melee attack within a certain time, and you couldn't go more than like 2 seconds in between each kill.The easiest way to achieve a bounty like this is to find an area where many enemies spawn at once, like the building in the middle of the cosmodrone where some people farm. I think 7 spawn at once, just turn the corner and blast them with a rocket launcher, problem solved. So you don't have to worry about how much time in between each kill!

Comment: I'm 99% sure it was because kills by players nearby count. I had a similar experience the other day.  It's probably somewhat related to the bug in Crucible where class kills (get 5,000 kills as a Warlock, etc.) count for you if someone of a different class is nearby and gets a kill.

Comment: @turbo I've been wondering how I keep getting Grimoire status updates for "X kills as a Y" when I'm playing a completely different class. (It's really funny when that happens and I've just finished *killing* a Y.) Never put that together with this before now. Thanks!

Comment: Was this bounty obtained in today's set? I will test it tonight. I am skeptical that what you describe is happening. If that is the case, it seems it could be a bug.

Comment: It was, @Travis

Comment: @Timelord64 - Was that on the Playstation? On xb1 I only found kill 30 with solar damage ("Kill it with fire").

Comment: No @Travis J. As I state in the very first sentence, I am running on xbox one.

Comment: @Timelord64 - The noted bounty was not available. Solar was though. Even with solar, I was able to confirm that both non fireteam kills and super kills did not affect the count. As this has not been reported at bungie's forum for bugs, I believe you must be mistaken.

Comment: @Travis J I am not mistaken. Perhaps it was the previous days set. I get access to two differant bounty sets in a single day due to the time differance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the error is in the numbers.

While it asks five kills in quick succession, it is more likely to respond to three or four kills.

Answer (score 1):

Through the  *Destiny 2.0.1*  update, this has been fix.

> Quests & Bounties
>
> - Fixed an issue where some Vanguard bounties were incorrectly granting credit across entire Fireteams
>
>   - Affected Bounties:
>     Heavyweight, Specialized Rampage, Enemy in Every Corner, Invincible

[Destiny Update 2.0.1](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/News?aid=13706)

Comment: As mentioned, I was not in a fireteam to be gaining credit from my fireteam

Comment: @Timelord64 Even though you may have not been in a fireteam, there are instances where it treat players in close proximity as if you are in a fireteam.

Comment: Also, for "fixed" this still regularly happens.